# If $X$ is paracompact then $f(X)$ not need to be paracompact

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

If $X$ is paracompact and $f:X \to Y$ is contínuous then $f(X)$ need not to be paracompact.

I've found this exercise at Munkres. My effort is the following:

I've proved that every discrete space is paracompact (since it is metrizable). My idea is define a function $f: X \to Y$ where $X$ is discrete (so, it is continuous), but I cannot find such function the way $f(X)$ is not paracompact. The only non paracompact space that I know is $S_\Omega \times \overline{S_\Omega}$, because it is Hausdorff, but not normal.

I don't know, maybe I can considerer the identity $I_d: S_\Omega \times \overline{S_\Omega} \to S_\Omega \times \overline{S_\Omega}$, where the topology on the domain is discrete.

Can you help me?

Comment: Then the topology $\Bbb R_K$ is even simpler (it's Hausdorff and non-regular). Also $S_\Omega$ as its product with a compact space is not normal. The square of the lower limit topology on $\Bbb R$ (the Sorgenfrey plane)  by non-normality too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any topological space $X$ which is *not* paracompact consider the identity map from $X$ endowed with the discrete topology into $X$ with its original topology. It's continuous and onto.

Comment: So is correct my idea? $I_d: S_\Omega \times \overline{S_\Omega} \to S_\Omega \times \overline{S_\Omega}$

Comment: Yes, but it works with *any* non-paracompact space. Other possibilities are the Moore plane and the Cartesian produc of the Sorgenfrey line by itself.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that $S_\Omega$ already is a non-paracompact   space. Simpler than yours.

Comment: @Joãonani Use $S_\Omega$ which is also non-paracompact. Sa. I consider this to be the simplest  example of a nice but not paracompact space.